# How can I auto minify .js files to .min.js when saving the .js version in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

So I'm using Sublime Text 3 on OS X

I'm also using [Minify](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Minify)

I know I can go into a .js file then Tools...Minify...Minify File and it creates the .min.js version in the same directory for me.  This works fine but I'm forgetful.  Is it possible (and if so how) to tap into Save in Sublime so that if I save a .js file it runs minify automatically for me?

Is this a case where I need a key binding for <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> that is smart enough to know if I'm saving a .js file and save/minify it if so and just do a standard save if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I've not found a good way to do this in Sublime Text but I did find [CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) for OS X. CodeKit runs along side Sublime and not only does it auto minify .js files it also runs it through JSLint to help catch issues. (It does more than that)

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason said, CodeKit is a great tool that runs along side sublime. Does compress LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript, JS, and I believe few more. That path for the compressed file is configurable. Once all files are set up, you leave CodeKit running and every single time you save a file in sublime CodeKit compiles.  If you are running a local host I believe that your browser reloads as well.

Answer (score 0):

When using Minify in Sublime Text, you can change the settings in *Preferences -> Package settings -> Minify -> Settings - User*, and add the line `"auto_minify_on_save": true,`. If the user settings are still empty, do not forget the curly brackets :

```
{
    "auto_minify_on_save": true
}
```

This will work whether you save with Ctrl + s or from the menu.